# Squid Reverse Proxy with SSL

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy, https, squid

I'm trying to use squid as a reverse proxy in front of a single website, to decrypt the SSL on the proxy and then to encrypt the connection to the webserver (this is in order to use squid as an ICAP client for a zero trust CDR product).

I can see that this requires two config lines:
`https_port 1.2.3.4:443 accel` for the listener
and
`cache_peer 1.2.4.8 parent 443` for the webserver.

Following the examples I've found here and elsewhere, I hit various errors from Squid, in particular this one:

```
FATAL: No valid signing certificate configured for HTTPS_port
```

A known-working configuration for Squid 4.x would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Evidently the examples I found were all for earlier versions of squid.

For this problem, my main takeaway was that `cert=` and `key=` in the `https_port` config line are no longer correct and we need to use `tls-cert=` and `tls-key=` instead.

So (for Squid v4.15) I just need the webserver certificate and its private key, and these lines in squid.conf:

```
https_port 1.2.3.4:443 accel defaultsite=mysite.com tls-cert=/etc/squid/myserver.pem
cache_peer 1.2.4.8 parent 443 0 no-query originserver login=PASS ssl
```

This works for a .PEM which includes the certificate and the unencrypted private key. If the key is in a separate file, this should work:

```
https_port 1.2.3.4:443 accel defaultsite=mysite.com tls-cert=/etc/squid/myserver.pem tls-key=/etc/squid/myserver.key
cache_peer 1.2.4.8 parent 443 0 no-query originserver login=PASS ssl
```

If that key is encrypted, you'll either need to start squid manually (eg run `squid -N` in a `screen` session) or add an `sslpassword_program` config line to provide the PEM passphrase.

NB:
I found that an http_port config line (eg `http_port 3128`) was still required for squid to start up.

All the configuration file directives are documented here: http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/